# Transaction stuck in "Pending"

Tags: ether, exchanges, ledger-nano-s

I've sent some ETH from the Ledger Live app to an exchange but I only used 1 Gwei and now the transaction is pending. It's been 20 hours. Will the transaction run out of gas eventually or will it go through?

I know it's possible to cancel a transaction with MEW but since I used Ledger Live, I'm not sure how to do it. Or would it just be better to wait?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @ethtrading13 did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same problem,

Answer (score 2):

**Increase the network fees (from ledger-website)**

*"For Bitcoin-like crypto assets, you can increase the network fees to accelerate your transaction. This functionality will be implemented in Ledger Live later."*

There is no way to send with a higher gas price. You are better off using MEW.

See this article here: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005198525-Transaction-stays-unconfirmed

Answer (score 0):

I went through the Support page of Ledger Live and found this.

A transaction can be pending due to these reasons:

- A transaction is pending if it hasn't received any confirmations yet.
- Transactions that included higher network fees normally don't stay pending for a long time.
- If a transaction included lower network fees, it can remain pending for a longer time.

Please go through this page for more info: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005307809